# How to measure storm performance - tuples per second?

Tags: cloud, bigdata, apache-storm

I want to check the storm performance on a cluster.
What is the best way to measure tuple/sec when working on storm cluster?

Comment: Storm UI can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the Storm UI. It gives you tuples sent in the last 10 mins, so you can just calculate your throughput from there. It also shows you at what capacity your bolt is running. Remember that throughput should be measured against percentage of CPU usage. If you're measuring 1000 tuples per second at 10% CPU usage, it means there is something else binding your application, for example I/O.

Alternatively, you can just have a spout or bolt log its throughput to a local file.